# How to add filter for each column in MatTableModule in Angular?

Tags: angular, datatable

All articles on filtering using MatTableModule suggest adding ONE MatInputModule where the user can enter the search/filter text:

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-label>Filter Product</mat-label>
<input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterValue"
(blur)="filterProduct(filterValue)" placeholder="Search product name">
</mat-form-field>
```

The above code snippet will call the function `filterProduct(...)` when the user enters a search/filter text.

And this is what the `filterProduct(...)` function looks like:

```
public filterProduct = (value: string) => {
this.dataSource.filter = value;
}
```

And this is the usual code that handles the filtering - `this.dataSource.filter = value;`

So this suggests the filter is applied to `all` the fields in `dataSource` which the MatTableModule data.

Is there a way to add separate filters to each field in the MatTableModule data?

Answer (score 0):

**Try Using**

If you having two colums with your table  item and cost make a form for the filter inputs and pass the value to the filter function like following:

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = ((data, filter) => {
  const a = !filter.item || data.item.toLowerCase().includes(filter.item);
  const b = !filter.cost || +data.cost === +filter.cost;
  return a && b;
}) as (Transaction, string) => boolean;

this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  const filter = {
    ...value,
    item: value.item.trim().toLowerCase()
  } as string;
  this.dataSource.filter = filter;
});
```

To Filter multiple Rows:

Here the stackblitz demo for multi filter: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uf1sdt-qbb81q?file=src/app/table-multiple-header-footer-example.html